# How can I generate a sitemap in a vue.js app?

Tags: vue.js, sitemap

I am trying to generate a sitemap in my vue. I have tried some plugins, but I have the problem that I don't know how to do it with my path structure.

For example, if my main path is:
https://example.com

Each of the clients have:
https://cliente.example.com

Comment: What is path structure and what problem do you have with a sitemap? The example with  https://cliente.example.com doesn't add clarity

Comment: All the plugins I have tried did not generate the sitemap file.

Comment: What exactly did you try and what did not work? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask